# Error 403 Wamp phpmyadmin

Tags: windows, wamp

Hi guys i thought i would ask in here cos well, ur all awesome. I made the big decision to upgrade to windows 8 (now believing its a bad one) i spent 4 hours trying to find a fix with my pen tablet on the internet due to my keyboard not working and a 100 other issues. But now this is the biggest - i have tried varying searches and come up with over 5000+ results on here and my issue is that wamp will not connect to phpmyadmin via localhost

my hosts file has 127.0.0.1 localhost in it -

my httpd.conf file has

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

and i get

Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server. I have spent 6 hours trying almost every solution even managed to screw everything up at about 2am and accidently delete the www folder back up file by accident and have now got fed up. I am on windows 8 pro - i have the latest wamp installed - the killer is it all works from 127.0.0.1/ but not from localhost/ if i change the allow from 127.0.0.1 it stops it working all together. please help it was working absolutely fine in windows 7 less than 48 hours ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it happens is IPV6. Windows 8 is by default an IPV6-first Operating System. How? Well just go to command-prompt and run the command

```
ping localhost
```

You will be getting response from ::1 i.e. the loopback address for IPV6. When you try to connect to the server it uses the port 80 along with IPV6 to locate it.

Check this post here.
http://praveenpuglia.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/setting-up-wamp-server-in-windows-8/

Comment: i did finally manage to get it working but at least now i know why it wasn't in the first place so many thanks